# Should we explicitly convert datetime to date or let SQL Server handle it

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008. I have declared a variable as Date. My table has a Datetime column which I'm fetching. When I assign the datetime to date variable, I only get a Date. Everything works good. But are there any performance implications of assigning DateTime to a Date variable without Convert/Cast and letting SQL Server handle it? Or is it advisable to Convert/Cast before we assign?

Comment: `DateTime` to `Date` is listed as a supported implicit conversion in the [conversion matrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) - you should be safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conversion from Datetime to Date is type of implicit conversion and it is defined in SQL server conversion so you do not need to be worry about conversion.

Obviously SQL Server would be using best bay of conversion for this so there is no need to add   extra overhead of conversion. Because the conversion method we use has been defined for explicit conversion.